# crear clases en C# como en Visual FoxPro

Tags: c#, datagrid

Masters. 
Estoy por iniciar mi primer proyecto en C#(soy desarrollador en Visual FoxPro), necesito crear unas clases visuales de Textbox y Grids(entre otros muchos mas) que voy a usar en casi el 90% del proyecto ya que deseo personalizarlos para estandarizar el sistema. Como se crean o no es factible hacerlo asi..

Gracias

MK

Comment: que serian esas clases visuales ? la idea es extender la funcionalidad los controles estandar que .net

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Si no sabes cómo hacer lo que describes en tu pregunta, investiga primero y actualiza tu pregunta con los enlaces de la investigación que hayas hecho. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Entiendo lo que buscas, soy programador C# y me tocó meterme en el lenguaje FoxPro donde las clases están enfocadas a controles de formulario, a mi parecer esta mal enfocado, ya que, las clases son entidades como la clase vehículo y sus objetos son vehiculoDePepe, vehiculoDeFer, etc. Por ello en las clases no están ligadas directamente a formularios, esto en c# y la mayoría de lenguajes. Y en los eventos de los controles es donde realizas el backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para personalizar los controles que .net provee podrias hacer uso de `Custom Control`

[Desarrollar controles personalizados de formularios Windows Forms con .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6hws6h2t(v=vs.110).aspx)

podrias heredar de un control existente y personalizarlo con propiedades y eventos

[Cómo: Heredar de controles de formularios Windows Forms existentes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/7h62478z(v=vs.110))

la base seria

```
public class CustomControl1 : System.Windows.Forms.Button{
  //aqui codigo personalizado
}
```

cuando compiles el control parecera en la toolbox para que lo puedas arrastrar en el diseñadro del form

Comment: En Visual FoxPro lo hacia todo(o casi todo) de manera visual y modificando sus propiedades. y estos se almacenaban como en un toolbox con mis clases propias y las arrastraba desde ahi a mis formularios.

Comment: @mickykhan, Creo que VisualFox en cuanto a creación de controles tenía más facilidad, pues los controles básicos que tiene son muy limitados, mientras que en C# son controles muy completos, con muchas funcionalidades ya integradas y un alto grado de facilidad para personalizar las características visuales, incluso sí WindowsForms no te satisface, puedes intentar utilizando la tecnología WPF, que te permite aún más libertad con los controles. Sí pudieras especificar qué cosas quieres agregar a los botones, se te podría decir sí ya viene integrado o la forma para integrarlo.

Comment: si quieres trabajar de forma visual tienes los UserControl, aunque estos estan mas pensados para componet funcionalidad reutilizable en lugar de personalizar un solo control concreto

Comment: Agradezco a todos sus aportes y sugerencias. Al parecer lo que necesitaba es aplicar " Controles Personalizados ". Es lo que hice y es casi lo que necesito. Ya cree un textbox, labels, combos..cuando creo la grilla y la pongo despues en mi form ya no puedo adicionarle mas columnas , es normal que no pueda editarlo mas cuando el control personalizado esta sobre mi form ??